# Simple LISP function not working

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I decided to learn LISP today, and have been playing around with it for a bit. I wrote a simple baby function just to test my understanding, and now understand that my understanding doesn't understand as much as I had understood it to understand. :D

Anyway, here is the function. The idea is that when it is called, e.g. (esexp base x) it should return the value base^x. So (esexp 3 4) = 3^4 = 81.

(I am using the CMU implementation of Common Lisp, if that matters.)

```
(defun esexp (base x)
  (if (= x 0)
      1
      (if (< x 0)
          (/ esexp (base (+ x 1)) base)
          (* esexp (base (+ x 1)) base))))
```

This doesn't work. I get errors that look like (Warning: This variable is undefined: SLBEXP) and (Error in KERNEL::UNBOUND-SYMBOL-ERROR-HANDLER:  the variable SLBEXP is unbound.) So. What am I doing wrong? AND would there be a better (or more LISP-ish way) to write this function?

ETA

Corrected code:

```
(defun esexp (base x)
  (if (= x 0)
      1
      (if (< x 0)
          (/ (esexp base (+ x 1)) base) 
          (* (esexp base (- x 1)) base))))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`esexp(base (+ x 1))`

should be

`(esexp base (+ x 1))`

`esexp` is a function just like `+`.  The syntax for invoking a function is

```
(function-name arg1 arg2 ...)
```

Answer (score 5):

The technical explanation of the error: the compiler was parsing the code:

```
(/ esexp(base (+ x 1)) base)
```

as this:

```
(/ esexp (base (+ x 1)) base)
```

which says:

- first, add 1 to the parameter `x`
- then, invoke a *function* called `base` with the result above.
- divide the value of a *variable* called `esexp` by the result above.
- then, divide that result by the parameter `base`. (The divide operator in Common Lisp can take more than two arguments.)

You see the trick? When a word appears as the first item in a s-expression (and that s-expression isn't quoted), it's usually treated as the name of a function you want to invoke. Otherwise, it's treated as the name of a variable whose value you want to retrieve. Further, in Common Lisp a symbol like `esexp` can be bound to both a *function* value and a *variable* value at the same time; context or special expressions like `#'esexp` (which means the function) are used to figure out which one you mean.

The compiler was telling you that, though `esexp` was bound to a *function* with your `defun` statement, it had not yet been bound to a *variable* value, and therefore could not be used as such. Hence, the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note about the code. I believe it should be

```
(defun esexp (base x)
        (if (= x 0)
                1
                (if (< x 0)
                        (/ (esexp(base (+ x 1)) base))
                        (* (esexp(base (- x 1)) base))))
```

Otherwise the function will never terminate. (you had `(* (esexp(base (+ x 1)) base))))`)